# .NET application access denied to create a subfolder in AppData folder

Tags: c#, .net

This has me a little bewildered at the moment.  I have a .NET application which I have made an installer for via WIX 3.5.  My app has some per-user files that it creates and uses during runtime so I am planning to create a `\MyApp` subfolder in AppData.

```
var directory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MyApp");

if(!Directory.Exists(directory)){
    Directory.Create(directory);
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work once the app is installed via the installer.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of using the Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData, use Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData

Comment: what if you want to roam?